# Ошибка в программе Си

Tags: c

ребята!
Написал код на си. И вот в чём ошибка: на следующей итерации переменные k и sch теряют своё значение. Не понимаю в чём ошибка?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скопируйте код в вопрос, а не прилагайте скрин

Comment: Внесите, пожалуйста, имеющий отношение к вопросу код в сам вопрос как текст. Заодно поясните, как вы это выяснили etc etc - словом, не стесняйтесь писать подробности :)

Comment: "Написал код на си." Но на скриншоте у файла явно расширение `.cpp`. Вы специально переводили компилятор в режим Си?

Answer (score 8):

Исправил вашу ошибку, проверяйте
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо) Только плохо фото видно.Напишите пожалуйста код в ответе.

Comment: @Andrew Каков вопрос, таков ответ. Вы проверили код в ответе? Если да, отметьте пожалуйста ответ как принятый.